# Windows Live Mail 2012 freezes upon startup after Windows 8 upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-live-mail

I recently upgrade form Windows 7 to Windows 8. The only problem I have is that whenever I open the latest WLM, it consistently freezes either on the loading screen or when trying to load my accounts (the shell of the program opens). I've tried completely removing it via Revo Uninstaller. I've also removed the "metro" mail app. I know it worked before, a while ago when I did a fresh install on another machine, but it seems to be broken after this upgrade.

I see no event logs in the viewer. I've tried reboots. No dice. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is to do with compatibility mode being enabled.

I had it on Windows 7 where you set it to run as Vista SP2 so you can minimize to tray. This doesn't work in Windows 8.

I tried un-installing but it remembered the mode. Try running normally and it should be okay albeit without the minimize to tray option.

Comment: It turned out I remembered this and it was the exact same issue, and for the exact same reason (minimizing to the tray). I removed the compatibility and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced problem.. Windows Live Mail stuck on startup screen and found below solution...

Though I removed completely windows live mail the problem was not solved. So i found that mail data file is corrupted and even after new install, data path is selected old folders which is stored in registry. I rename the old data file folder and magically wlm started with new data folder then I imported mails from renamed folders.

Comment: If you have an answer, please state it, clearly, in proper English, with proper capitalization, punctuation, etc.  Please don’t tell us about the things that you tried that didn’t work unless they’re really *really **really*** relevant to your actual answer.